# How to use arpa file in voice recognition

Tags: voice-recognition, cmusphinx, language-model

I have created a ARPA file from a text file using CMU SLM toolkit.

Currently I don't know how to use the generated ARPA file in my project instead of `.lm` and `.dic` file.

If any one knows about that please let me know.

Comment: hi how to create dictionary file.am still stuck in creating .lm file so please let me know the procedure of creating .dic and .lm file.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you use the probability of the language model when considering the "cost" of a word-transition in the search.
:-)  but that's probably not what you wanted to hear.

Your question is too open-ended.. what is your specific problem?

The dictionary and the language model are two separate items -- you can not convert one into the other.

The dictionary is used to tell the search what the valid words are and how they relate to phonemes / the phonetic transcription.

The language model is used during the recognition of an utterance, by using the probability of a uni-gram, bi-gram, n-gram .. when the search algorithm is considering a word-transition.

**Edit:**

check:

http://www-speech.sri.com/projects/srilm/manpages/ngram-format.5.html

http://www.ee.ucla.edu/~weichu/htkbook/node243_ct.html

http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~bromberg/ngramcount/ngram2fsm.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply tilo.yes i know that both .dic and .lm are different.currently i generated a .arpa file from corpus.txt file using slmtools.but my question is how to convert .arpa into .lm format.? and creating a dictionary file is a seperate question sorry for mixing both of them.